# How to automatically send GET data from a php script

Tags: php

I've got a php script and I want to call another php script from within it which logs data.

Problem is I need to send variables and `include ('log.php?log=a&dob=fromtest');` is not working as it's saying the script is not found. If I take the variables out then the script is found no problem.

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the variable in your code.

```
$_GET['log'] = 'a';
$_GET['dob'] = 'fromtest';
include('log.php');
```

But the proper way to do it is to write a class for it.

Should look like this:

**logManager.class.php**

```
class logManager {

  public function addLog($log, $dob) {
    /* do you logging */
  }

  // example for get log items
  public function getLog($log, $limit) {
    /* do your get log item thing */
  }

}
```

**LogThis.php**

```
require_once('logManager.class.php');

$log = new LogManager();
$log->addLog('a', 'fromtest');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you include a file i would recommend you to make a function and then call the function with parameters like this:

log.php:

```
<?php

    function xy($log, $dob) {
        //do something

    }
?>
```

in your script:

```
<?php

    require_once("log.php");

    xy("a", "fromtest");

?>
```

Or you use the `header();` function like this:

```
header("Location: log.php?log=a&dob=fromtest");
```

Answer (score 0):

The parser will interpret that **(log.php?log=a&dob=fromtest)** as a file name which is very wrong because no such script file exists.I suggest you consider using the header function to access a script sending variables at the same time . Take for example this site when you 're trying to login, the url will be like.

```
http://so/login/?return_url=http://mycurrentpage/
```